# SQL Server MCSA / MCSE Training Software for iOS

Tags: ios, offline, educational

I am looking for recommendations for a software application to assist in the overall study and to drill myself on the content related to SQL Server Administration, particularly Microsoft Certification tests [Administering SQL Server 462](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-462.aspx?c=eh) and [Implementing a Data Warehouse with SQL Server 463](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-463.aspx?c=eh).

I travel a lot and so being able to use it on the road / airport / airplane would be nice, and thus the iOS & offline usage request.. but something that runs on the PC or a Mac OS also works.

I am **not** looking for a T-SQL quizzer/flashcards, an offline [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), or something focused just on the basics of Microsoft test [461 Querying Microsoft SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/exam-70-461.aspx?c=eh) which a lot of the iOS apps in the App Store I immediately found seemed to focus on or there content.

I am open to INTERACTIVE eBooks apps with built in INTERACTIVE tutorials though; and not just looking for PDF or Brain Dumps put in application form such as many apps on the app store by [Aashita Jadhav](https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/aashita-jadhav/id612227650) which seem to dominate many search results.. but something INTERACTIVE.